# st_ delaunay returning empty geometry from 3D points

Tags: postgis, postgresql

**The Data**

I have a 3D point dataset, one row looks like this

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT (geom) FROM pc_processing.top_dist
SRID=32635;POINT(580992.318 4275265.0982 191.284)
... +1000 more
```

**The problem**

I want to triangulate in 3D so I try the

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT (ST_DelaunayTriangles(geom,0,0))
```

But if I select the following I get

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT (ST_DelaunayTriangles(geom,0,0))
FROM pc_processing.top_dist
SRID=32635;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
....
```

So, how do I return a Delaunay triangulation from 3D point data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST_DelaunayTriangles` operates on *point sets* to create a mesh from the input, and if you pass only *one* point at a time, well, the whole thing becomes rather pointless (pun or no pun unintended).

I.e. you want to pass in any geometry that consists of more than three points (actually two, I guess, but again: rather pointless); in your case you could pass in a *MultiPoint*:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom), 0, 0))
FROM pc_processing.top_dist;
```

where you could also add e.g. a `GROUP BY` if needed.